# Spawning a jQuery modal dialog from another open modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Can this be done? 
I've been messing around for a while with the jQuery UI dialog without much success.

Thanks...

Comment: "Can this be done?", can you please elaborate a little further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier to refine your User Interface. Nesting Modal dialogs might not be the best way to help the user achieve the task, and it might make it simpler to code.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/us-cranky12.html

Comment: I was toying with the idea of nesting modal dialogs because the second modal is already functional and it would then be plain as-is reuse. Thanks